# Fail Network Error Download PDF using iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iis, iis-7.5

I inherited an .net application that allows users to download a pdf. Now, I am able to download the pdf file when I run locally but when I deploy to IIS server I run into problems. The download works on Firefox but doesnt work on Chrome, and sometimes on IE. The fact that I can download it on my local development environment tells that it could be something with IIS configuration or maybe my code. The pdf is stored in ms sql server 2012 table as varbinary. I provided some code below that is used to read the data. Please let me know if there are other information you all need. Also, I checked the iis logs and I am getting 200 status codes for everything. Nothing stands out in there.

```
if(Session["DetailID"] != null)
{   
    //get the file
    DataTable dt = sp_Attachment_Download(lblAttachmentIDD.Text);
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

    string name = (string)row["AFileName"];
    string contentType = (string)row["AFileType"];
    Byte[] data = (Byte[])row["AFile"];

    /// Send the file to the browser
    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    Response.BinaryWrite(data);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
}
```

EDITED----------
I am using the developer tools for IE and Chrome and found something interesting. Chrome gives me the following error when I click on the link:

```
interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf:
```

IE doesnt give an error but something caught my attention. I my REQUEST header, ACCEPT does not contain application/pdf and the RESPONSE Content-Type has application/pdf. Could this be something? How can I set the ACCEPT to include application/pdf in aspx page?

Comment: I also ran into a similar issue, the download fails in Chrome with message 
 Failed- Network Error. But I noticed that the issue was with the protocols, Chrome was using HTTP/2 while Firefox was using HTTP/1.1. Did you observe this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had kinda similar issue when downloading pdf from chrome as in my case filename had a comma in it and that chrome apparently didn't like it, so I removed comma from filename and it worked.
PS: Please try not to use `Response.Close()`. It aborts the thread and throws exception.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName.Replace(",",&#44;");
Response.CacheControl = "No-cache";
Response.Write(data);
Response.Flush();
Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, here's my code to do the same thing.  One thing that I noticed is that you're not specifying the file length, which I believe is required. Please note that pFileData is class that contains FileName, a string, and FileData, a byte[].

```
        System.Web.HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + pFileData.FileName);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pFileData.FileData.Length.ToString());
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        Response.BinaryWrite(pFileData.FileData);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.SuppressContent = true;
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        Response.End();
```